# How to solve IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I tried to write a review in a form,but after submitting the form it shows an error.I tried different ways to solve this issue but in vein.Actually I create a review form in such a way that any user can submit their review using this form or they can update their previous review.Here I used try and except methods.Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

I got a Traceback like this:

```
Internal Server Error: /User_Reviews/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\movie\review\views.py", line 42, in user_reviews
ureview = reviews.objects.get( movie__id=movies_id,user__id=request.user.id)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
review.models.reviews.DoesNotExist: reviews matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
db.query(q)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'movie_id' cannot be null")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\movie\review\views.py", line 54, in user_reviews
data.save()
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
return manager._insert(
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\movie_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 78, in execute
raise IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'movie_id' cannot be null")
```

Html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'user_reviews' movies.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="title">Title</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="review">Review</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="review" id="review" placeholder="Review">
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rating" id="rating" placeholder="Rating">
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('User_Reviews/<int:movies_id>', views.user_reviews, name="user_reviews"),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
def user_reviews(request,movies_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')   
    if request.method=='POST':
        try:          
            ureview = reviews.objects.get( movie__id=movies_id,user__id=request.user.id)
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST,instance=ureview)
            form.save()
            return redirect(url)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = reviews()
                data.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
                data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                data.save()
                return redirect(url)
```

models.py:

```
    class reviews(models.Model):
        movie = models.ForeignKey(details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
        review = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
        rating = models.FloatField()
        ip = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
        status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

movie field is not nullabale, so you should assign a details object to this field:

```
data.movie = details.objects.get(id=movie_id)
```

or you can make it nullable:

```
movie = models.ForeignKey(details, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: When I give `data.movie = details.objects.get(id=movie_id)` I got TypeError .So I assign movies_id to `data.movie` I got the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_reviews(request,movies_id):
url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if request.method=='POST':
    try:
        ureview = reviews.objects.get(movie__id=movies_id,user__id=request.user.id)
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST,instance=ureview)#If the logined user already post a review,instance=ureview given in ReviewForm update the current review
        form.save()
        messages.success(request,'Your review has been updated')
        return redirect(url)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)#If the logined user did not post any review,use this code
        if form.is_valid():
            data = reviews()
            data.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            data.movie_id = movies_id
            data.user_id = request.user.id
            data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
            data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your review has been submitted')
            return redirect(url)
```

When I rewrite the views.py I got the correct output